# Weird Node.js Buffer.toString() behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've had some issues with making `Buffer` into `String` and other way round.

When I did

```
var b = new Buffer(4);
b.writeInt32BE(1000);
var c = new Buffer(b.toString());
```

It has returned a whole different value. so I've made a little test

```
for(var i = 0; i < 255; i++){
    var a = String.fromCharCode(i);
    console.log(i + " " + (new Buffer(a)[0] == a.charCodeAt(0)));
 }
```

And it returns true for 0-126, but false 127-255
Can anyone tell me what is the difference in these methods, and how to turn `Buffer` into `String` so it can be made a `Buffer` again?

**//Edit**

Same for

```
new Buffer('\u0079')
```

returns

```
<Buffer 79>
```

while

```
new Buffer('\u0080')
```

returns

```
<Buffer c2 80>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not taking into account the character encoding that node is using when it converts the binary data to a string. By default, it uses UTF-8.

UTF-8 will encode bytes that are < 128 so that it maps to the same character code. However, for 128 and up it will instead encode it - basically, bytes with the first bit set to 1 are special in UTF-8 encoding. UTF-8 also works on multi-byte sequences, so it treats sets of two types when encoding.

[Wikipedia gives a good explanation here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Decimal 1000, which is hex 0x3e8, would thus result in the following bytes when utf-8 encoded: DF 98

If you decode it from string to buffer using UTF-8 again it should round-trip correctly. You can also specify a different encoding when calling the Buffer constructor or toString methods, see the node docs for details.

Comment: Do You know any encoding that would allow me to make use of all 8 bits, not just 7?

Comment: @KrzysztofWende You could use the `'binary'` encoding if you really have to use strings (e.g. `new Buffer('\u0080', 'binary')`). But you can also pass in an array of bytes (e.g. `new Buffer([0x80])`) or a Typed Array too.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you're trying to use them as bytes, why not just leave them in a buffer?

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced with same issue. To answer your question `how to turn Buffer into String so it can be made a Buffer again`, you need to convert it to `base64` encoded string. That way you won't lose any data:

```
buf = Buffer(4)
buf.fill(128)
base64String = buf.toString('base64')
newBuf = Buffer(base64String, 'base64')
buf.equals(newBuf) //true
```